# Anchor Tags lower on my page Disappear when I use absolute positioning to position my menu

Tags: css

I am using this to position my menu, it works across all browsers but the links (anchor tags) in the rest of my page stop working.

The menu is in the perfect spot but none of the links or image-map  will work in most browsers

Sorry I am new to this

could you peek at the source code -thanks
I am really trying to get this but i am sure stuck.

**Success! - Removing the bottom:0 worked - thanks to all who helped.  I am most grateful!**

Comment: Could you show us the code that's not working?

Comment: I need to see more code. Can you show both the HTML and the CSS. And more detailed please :)

Comment: Sorry I am new to this Here is the link - http://www.himalayahomes.com/index-test.html

could you peek at the source code

Answer (score 1):

```
<div align="center" style="margin: auto; left: 0pt; right: 0pt; bottom: 0pt; position: absolute; top: 197px; z-index: 1;">
```

Remove the "bottom: 0pt" and everything is fine for this problem.

But one thing, you should put the styles for this div in your css file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay...without code it's next to impossible to give you the right answer, and since your (x)html defines what CSS gets called, showing us one part of the puzzle isn't enough. Still...

1. 1. Have you remembered to place a `position:relative` on the parent element of whatever you're positioning absolutely?
2. 2. If you're positioning the  elements to the same absolute position, there's a good chance that they're going to overlap and be hidden by the upper-most/last of the positioned elements
3. Use semantics and established techniques to help yourself learn:

   1. [howtocreate.co.uk](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/testMenu.html)
   2. [Css play.co.uk](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/)
   3. ...and so many others: [Google search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+html+menu)

Comment: Thanks but it is not the menu that is the problem - the menu works perfectly, the anchor tags lower on the page just stop working when this coding is used. on the div that hold the menu style="margin:auto; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; position:absolute; top:197px, when I remove the absolute the anchor tags work again but I need the absolute to position the menu perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think that removing the bottom: 0pt; should do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

You were specifying both top:0 and bottom:0 so the div was stretched larger than the menu height.

Because absolute positioning takes it out of the flow and puts the div in its own layer, it was covering the links.

Besides removing the bottom:0, you can remove most of the other styles too.

```
<div align="center" style="position: absolute; top: 197px;">
```

Comment: thanks for explaining that - makes perfect sense.

Very grateful for the help